# How to create a very large (more than INT_MAX) character buffer?

Tags: visual-c++

I am dealing with very large files, frequently over 2GBs, and need to dump them into a buffer to be able to deal with them.

I create the buffer like this:

```
char* bigBuffer = nullptr;
...
bigBuffer = new char[3'000'000'000];
```

The line that allocates the memory shows the following warning when all warnings are enabled: `C4310 cast truncates constant value`

I tried explicitly telling the compiler this is not an `int` by changing the line to:

```
bigBuffer = new char[3'000'000'000ull];
```

but I'm still getting the same warning. Seems like it is casting it implicitly to an `int` no matter what.

How do I get the compiler to allow me to create this array in the way I want, or even larger if needed?

I am on the latest version of Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: The argument for the `new[]` operation has the `size_t` type. What platform are you targeting? 64-bit target uses a 64-bit unsigned for that type but 32-bit target uses a 32-bit unsigned.

Comment: Curiously, this avoids the warning: `size_t BufSize = 3'000'000'000uLL; bigBuffer = new char[BufSize];`.

Comment: @AdrianMole I'm targeting 64 bits. Your solution to avoid the warning makes it seem like there is a bug in the compiler

Comment: Bug? In Microsoft products? How dare you even *suggest* such a thing! ;-P But yeah - seems like it, to me!